# How to pipe a number into bc elegantly?

Tags: pipe, xargs, stdin, bc

Is there a more elegant way than using `xargs -Ix` for the following?

```
echo "283" | xargs -Ix bc -l -e "scale=2; l( x )/l(10)"
```

Comment: @jesse_b `-e` takes an expression to evaluate.  This is an extension found on [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bc&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+12.2-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html) and [OpenBSD](https://man.openbsd.org/bc).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Those are acutaly where this example lives at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really see a reason for `xargs` here:

```
printf 'scale=2; l(%s)/l(10)\n' "283" | bc -l
```

Alternatives for when the number is read from a file:

```
awk '{ printf "l(%s)/l(10)\n", $1 }' file | bc -l -e 'scale=2'
```

(that's assuming a `bc` that has `-e`), or without `bc` at all:

```
awk '{ printf "%.2f\n", log($1)/log(10) }' file
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess in this case `xargs` helps if the numbers is the end of a pipe, e.g in `cat file | xargs printf 'scale=2; l(%s)/l(10)\n' | bc -l`

Comment: @2419 Then I would rather do `awk '{ printf "l(%s)/l(10)\n", $1 }' file | bc -l -e 'scale=2'` or just `awk '{ printf "%.2f\n", log($1)/log(10) }' file` without `bc` at all.

Answer (score 0):

Untested with `bc`, as my `bc` has no `-e`, however these should work.

`echo "283" | xargs echo 123` can be replaced with.
`echo 123 "$(echo "283")"`

So for your example

`bc -l -e "scale=2; l( x )/l(10)" "$(echo "283")"`